# repeatedly calling a method in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's consider a list called 'my_list` whose contents are as follows:

`['10', '100', '1,000', '10,000', 100,000']`

I want to verify that my_list is a list of stringified integers, which are multiples of 10 and are sorted in ascending order, so here's what i do

`int_list = [int(each_int.replace(',', '')) for each_int in my_list]`

`boolean = all([int_list[idx] == int_list[idx-1]*10 for idx in xrange(1, len(int_list))])`

my question is will the `len()` be called for every iteration? what is better practice in such cases?

1. assign the length to a variable and use that instead of the len() itself in the list comprehension
2. it doesn't matter, len() is executed only once for all the iterations

if 2. , is it applicable to cases when say, I am iterating through the values/ keys of a dictionary of lists (or maybe just a dictionary)

ex: `d_list = [set(value) for value in my_dict.values()]`

Comment: `len` will only be called once, when passed into `xrange`, after which the comprehension will iterate over the result of `xrange`. Similarly, with `my_dict.values()` the call only happens once. It's effectively the same as with a `for` loop: the loop constructor only occurs once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
my_list = ['10', '100', '1,000', '10,000', '100,000']

int_list = [int(each_int.replace(',', '')) for each_int in my_list]

>>> print all(i*10==j for i,j in zip(int_list, int_list[1:]))
True
```

This will avoid any unnecessary repetitions of calculations and is also my faster since it is doing comparison by division. I have also replaced `all([...])` with `all(...)` since `all` can handle generators and will save from having to create a temporary list.

Comment: Note that in Python 2, (which the questioner appears to be using), your division check won't work, as for any integer `j` between 100 and 109, `j / 10 == 10` will be `True`. You can work around this of course, with a `float` call or with `from __future__ import division`, but keeping multiplication check from the question seems like it would be simpler. Your `zip` iteration is better though!